# Confidence interval distribution in the interval

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval

If we have result of study wich investigated effect of some intervention on the incidence of stroke and we got results of study to be HR 0.9 (95% CI 0.85-1.05).
Is it the same chance that the intervention increases incidence of stroke for 5% and decreases incidence of stroke for 10%?
Can we assume that the distribution of values within the CI is uniform or normal?

Thank you in advance :)